# iOS App: "Unhandled Exception" when running in Visual Studio -- No errors in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mvvmcross

So we have an application we've built in Visual Studio using MvvmCross and PCLs.   Recently we added James Montemagno's  MvvmCross Settings plugin (Refractored.MvxPlugin.Settings) to the iOS project.

We added the appropriate Settings.bundle Root.plist file to get the settings we want added into the iOS settings area.    When we run under Xamarin Studio all is well.

However,  when we run from within Visual Studio the application fails at startup with this output:

```
Launching Application for debugging...
Starting debug session...
Debug session started...
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/monotouch.dll         [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/PharosPrintiOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/PharosPrint.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/CrossUI.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/CrossUI.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Refractored.MvxPlugins.Settings.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Runtime.dll
2014-04-16 13:52:44.766 PharosPrintiOS[3951:70b] Could not load 'PharosPrintiOS' for registration: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:351 
  at MonoTouch.Registrar.OldDynamicRegistrar.RegisterAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/OldDynamicRegistrar.cs:67 
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Windows.dll [External]
2014-04-16 13:52:44.769 PharosPrintiOS[3951:70b] This could be due to an outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/PharosPrintiOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
2014-04-16 13:52:44.971 PharosPrintiOS[3951:70b] Could not load 'Refractored.MvxPlugins.Settings' for registration: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:351 
  at MonoTouch.Registrar.OldDynamicRegistrar.RegisterAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/OldDynamicRegistrar.cs:67 
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.dll
2014-04-16 13:52:44.972 PharosPrintiOS[3951:70b] This could be due to an outdated assembly kept by the simulator, location: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Refractored.MvxPlugins.Settings.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Threading.Tasks.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/PCLWebUtility.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/Refractored.MvxPlugins.Settings.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/WYPopover.Touch.dll
Loaded assembly: /Users/fcaico/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/EE93AB27-23E2-4197-8236-9FA778FE5446/PharosPrintiOS.app/BTProgressHUD.dll
2014-04-16 13:52:45.593 PharosPrintiOS[3951:70b] *** Assertion failure in int UIApplicationMain(int, char **, NSString *, NSString *)(), /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIApplication.m:2448
An unhandled exception occurred.
```

The exception stack is largely empty:

```
[External Code] 
>   0x8 in PharosPrint.iOS.App.Main at y:\Projects\PharosPrint\PharosPrint.iOS\Main.cs:17   C#
```

I'm fairly convinced this has something to do with the settings plugin because if I simply comment out the SettingsPluginBootstrap class everything works fine again.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?  I'd really rather not stop using Visual Studio over this...

Comment: What happens if you create a new visual studio solution and reimplement it?  Xamarin Studio solutions sometimes look different in the actual solution file.